# ASP.net Gridview multiple value condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my SQL Server database, there is a column `visible in app` and the value is 0,1,2. I want to show its data in gridview column by using condition like `0 = No`, `1 = Mobile`, `2 = App`

The code is like this ..

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Visibility In App">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("VisibleInDevice").ToString()=="0" ? "No" : "Mobile"  %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Show us what have you tried and what is not working and ask the specific question.

Comment: Yep like Nikem said. The ternary operator that you have used is the right approach for what you want to do....so what is the problem? Are you getting an exception? If so probably need to show your databinding logic

Comment: <%#Eval("VisibleInDevice").ToString()=="0" ? "No" : Eval("EmpType").ToString()=="1"?"Mobile":"APP" %>

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to view or hide rows based on the flag `visible in app`

There is many ways you can do this, but one similar to what you have you need something like:

```
<div class='<%#Eval("VisibleInDevice").ToString()=="0" ? "No" : Eval("VisibleInDevice").ToString()=="2" ? "App" : "Mobile"  %>'>
.
.
.
</div>
```

you can now hide and show items based on the classes `.No` `.App` `.Mobile`